# SMS intent does not close when press send

Tags: java, android

```
Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
smsIntent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:" + Uri.encode(MobileNumber)));
smsIntent.putExtra("exit_on_sent", true); //this line doesn't work
startActivity(smsIntent);
```

How to make this line work?

Comment: Can you provide a describtion of what happens instead of the wanted result instead of just "doesn't work"

Comment: I send a message, and the only way to return to the activity is to press the back button

Comment: does the sms get send successfully?

Comment: @JoeMatt yes it does

Comment: Not all SMS apps are going to respect that extra.

Comment: But I am only planning on going to the default one that google. Like the main one when you get the phone. How do I return back to the main activity once a message is sent without using permissions, so I can fit the new policy coming out.

Comment: There is no documentation about this so can someone explain the situations that this line of code works?

Comment: "There is no documentation about this..." – Exactly. There is, also, no requirement for any given SMS app to acknowledge and obey that extra. And there really is no such thing as "the default one that google. Like the main one when you get the phone". Whichever apps come pre-installed on a particular device is ultimately up to the manufacturer and carrier.

Answer (score 0):

**This code will send sms on your button click without going to the message box**

```
String sendMessage = "Your Message";
                SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                PendingIntent sentPI;
                String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
                sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);
                sms.sendTextMessage("MOBILE NUMBER", null, sendMessage, sentPI, null);
```

**And Yaa don't forget to add Permission in Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

Comment: Sooner or later can't use the permission unless the app is the default sms app.

Comment: Also I need the app to go to the messaging app, so the user can send a message and once the message is sent, the SMS intent should close, returning to the intent

Comment: Then there is no way, It depends on the default messaging app